# Index out of range error , Can someone please tell me where Its going wrong

Tags: python, indexing

This is my function so far:

```
def fizzbuzz(intList):   
    strList = list[]
    for i in range(0,len(intList)):
        if intList[i] % 3== 0 and intList[i] % 5==0:
            strList[i] = "FizzBuzz"
        elif intList[i] % 3 == 0:
            strList[i] = "Fizz"
        elif intList[i] % 5 == 0:
            strList[i] = "Buzz"
        else:
            strList[i] = str(intList[i])
    return strList
```

This is what i'm basically supposed to do:

1. For numbers that are multiples of three replace the integer with the string "Fizz".
2. For numbers that are multiples of five replace the integer with the string "Buzz".
3. For numbers that are multiples of both three AND five replace the integer
   with the string `"FizzBuzz"`

Your function should take in a list of integers as input.
Your function should not modify the input list.
Your function should return an updated list with integers and strings.

Comment: `strList = list[]` is this python? correct it as `strList = list()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating (most likely, that is) an *empty list* with `strList = list()` and then accessing it `strList[i]` at an index that does not exist -- the `strList` is empty, *any indexing operation on it* will raise an `IndexError`.

You should be *copying* the original list instead with `[:]` (or `list(intList)`, or `[*intList]` if on Python 3.5):

```
strList = intList[:]
```

Now, when you index `strList` you'll use the index that corresponds to the current number in `intList` you're iterating through.

Comment: Thanks Jim! You were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing `strList` based on the length of `intList`. This will only work if strList and intList are the same length.

To create a list you must also use correct syntax `list()` as opposed to `list[]`

In addition, you have created `strList` to be an empty string meaning you do not have to use `strList[i]` to assign values to each index (seemingly impossible).

A solution to this problem is to use `.append(value)`. I've created a solution as seen below:

```
def fizzbuzz(intList):
    strList = list()
    for i in range(0,len(intList)):
        if intList[i] % 3== 0 and intList[i] % 5==0:
            strList.append("FizzBuzz")
        elif intList[i] % 3 == 0:
            strList.append("Fizz")
        elif intList[i] % 5 == 0:
            strList.append("Buzz")
        else:
            strList.append(str(intList[i]))
    return strList
```

Here the function will create the strList, iterate through each value in the given intList. Depending on the value the function will append your desired value to the list. Finally, returning a new list build on words and numbers.

Comment: Thanks Mitchell! your solution seemed to make it very clear where I went wrong!

Comment: I am glad I could help! :)